# How can I use React component as an enhancer?

Tags: reactjs, relayjs

I'm a newbie and React and I've got the following piece of code:

```
class MyCoolComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <QueryRenderer
        environment={environment}
        query={graphql`
          query UserQuery {
            viewer {
              id
            }  
          }
        `}
        variables={{}}
        render={({error, props}) => {
          if (error) {
            return <div>Error!</div>;
          }
          if (!props) {
            return <div>Loading...</div>;
          }
          return <div>User ID: {props.viewer.id}</div>;
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

I want to use this React component as an *enhancer* to a different React Component to pass the data (`props.viewer.id`) using `compose(addDataEnhancer, ...)` to the other High Order Component (such that it'll be able to use `props.viewer.id`). How can I do it?

The context: the idea is to use this `MyCoolComponent` as a replacement for the data source function here:

```
export default compose(
  // data source
  graphql(gql`query MyQuery1 { ... }`),
)(MyHOCComponent);
function MyHOCComponent({ data }) {
  console.log(data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work. `compose` will call first hoc with base component, than return value (wrapped component) is passed to next hoc (next `compose` argument), etc...
Base component (and every HOC listed after this HOC) will have prop `viewerId`

```
// withViewerId.js

import React from 'react'
import { QueryRenderer, graphql } from 'react-relay'
import environment from 'environment'

export default (BaseComponent) => (restProps) => (
  <QueryRenderer
    environment={environment}
    query={graphql`
      query UserQuery {
        viewer {
          id
        }  
      }
    `}
    variables={{}}
    render={({error, props}) => {
      if (error) {
        return <div>Error!</div>;
      }
      if (!props) {
        return <div>Loading...</div>;
      }
      return <BaseComponent {...restProps} viewerId={props.viewer.id} />;
    }}
  />
)
```

usage:

```
import withViewerId from 'withViewerId'

export default compose(withViewerId)(BaseComponent)
```